# How to stack a node over the center of another node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I put a node exactly over the center of another node, so that the two centers of the nodes overlap?

In the following example the node `two` should be positioned in the center of the green node `one`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (one) [circle, fill=green, scale=10] {};

   % The following does not work.
   % pgfkeys complains I do not know the key '/tikz/center of'
   \node (two) [center of=one] {Hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
\node (two) [blah…] at (one.center) { text-content };
```

should do the trick.

Based on “13.5 Placing Nodes Using Anchors” in tikzpgfmanual.pdf (page 123 or so).

Comment: As I show in my answer, your suggestion also work as `\node (two) [blah…] at (one) { text-content };`

Answer (score 2):

TikZ has not defined positioning `center`. In the context you expected it to work, you should use `at`. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm, many]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (zero) [circle, fill=green] {};
    \node (one) [circle, fill=red, scale=5] at (3,0) {};
    \node (two) [at={(one)}] {Hi};  % <---
% or simpler
    \node (one) [circle, fill=cyan, scale=5] at (6,0) {};
    \node (two) at (one) {Hi};      % <---
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]